# Registering a script dilemma→ wp_register_script

Tags: wp-register-script

```
wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

If `$ver` is not required then should we leave that space blank? or completely remove the commas?

Example →

```
wp_register_script( 'scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
```

There is no dependency on JQuery. this needs to be removed entirely:

```
, array( 'jquery' ),
```

or leave it blank like this →

```
    wp_register_script( 'scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js', , '1.1', true );
```

Comment: Leaving it blank would be invalid PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply pass in `null` or the empty equivalent.

For example, if you don't depend on anything, say so. It's expecting an array of the dependencies, so pass an empty array `array()`

Or pass in `null`

Answer (score 0):

you cant leave it empty, at least you have to put an empty string `''`, it will default the dependency to `array()` and the version to `false`:

```
wp_register_script( 'scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js', '','' , true );
```

for readability you can, and its used widely:

```
wp_register_script( 'scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js', array(), null , true );
```

with would be just the same.

Comment: You can't leave it blank, it will throw a syntax error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' `.

Comment: true, i answered checking the core code, i updated my answer